# Tags not working in my custom post type

Tags: custom-post-types, tags

I created new post type and support tags like this:

```
'supports'   => array(
                            'title',
                             'thumbnail',
                             'editor',
                             'date',
                              'excerpt',
                               'comments', 
                               'custom-fields', 
                               'tags')
                    )
```

But when go to admin area and post a new post in my site, I cannot see Tags, why !

Comment: If you click the "Screen Options" tab at the top of the page, can you see a "Tab" check box?

Comment: i do that but i cannot see it in the top

Answer (score 2):

"Tags" are a taxonomy and should be registered using the `taxonomy` argument, not the `supports` argument.

> > **taxonomies**   (array) (optional) An array of registered taxonomies like `category` or `post_tag` that will be used with this post
> >     type. This
> >     can be used in lieu of calling `register_taxonomy_for_object_type()`
> >     directly. Custom taxonomies still need to be registered with
> >     `register_taxonomy()`.
> >     Default: no taxonomies
>
> https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_post_type#Arguments

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify it as a taxonomy. So in addition to your supports argument you can pass through taxonomies like this:

```
'taxonomies' => array('post_tag')
```

Also note it's post_tag, not just tag.